# Akka Actors not receiving any message after using the same Actor class multiple times.

Tags: java, spring-boot, akka, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

An instance of an akka actor is not receiving any message.

Here's our actor. The actor runs a kafka consumer upon receiving a message.

```
package package1.akka;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import package.kafka.SimpleConsumer;
import package.utils.StringUtils;
import kafka.consumer.ConsumerIterator;
import kafka.consumer.KafkaStream;
import kafka.javaapi.consumer.ConsumerConnector;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import akka.actor.ActorSelection;
import akka.actor.UntypedActor;


@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class TestAKKAActor  extends UntypedActor{

    private @Value("${kafka}") String kafka;

    ActorSelection messageParentActor = AkkaFactory
            .getActorSystem(SystemType.LOCAL)
            .actorSelection("akka://AKKASystem/user/messageParentActor");


    Logger logger = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestAKKAActor.class);

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object arg0) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("hi! message recieved");
        processAkkaMessage("x"+StringUtils.generateRandomKey(5));
        if(arg0.equals(Msg.DONE)){
            context().system().shutdown();
        }

    }

    public void processAkkaMessage(Object arg0){

        // topic has to be 16 digit
        String topic = arg0.toString();
        String randomFiller = StringUtils.generateRandomKey(4)
                + StringUtils.generateRandomKey(4);
        String group = "c" + randomFiller;
        logger.info("Consumer Activating for >> {}", topic);
        SimpleConsumer csc = new SimpleConsumer(kafka+ ":2181", group);

        ConsumerConnector consumerConnector = csc.getConsumerConnector();
        Map<String, Integer> topicCountMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        topicCountMap.put(topic, new Integer(1));

        Map<String, List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>>> consumerMap = consumerConnector
                .createMessageStreams(topicCountMap);

        KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]> stream = consumerMap.get(topic).get(0);

        ConsumerIterator<byte[], byte[]> it = stream.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {

            String newString = new String(it.next().message());

            try {
                System.out.println(newString);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        context().stop(getSelf());;
    }



}
```

The class below has a method test() which creates 5 different references of the same actor and starts 5 different consumers using a for loop. The method test() is being triggered using an RESTFUL api. But the actor only recieves message upto the 3rd actor. Actors after that dont receive any message and hence dont start any new consumers. I need to start as many consumers as possible but can't seem to get past three consumer threads.

We've looked into memory issues as well but that doesn't seem to be the problem.

If we remove the consumer codes the actors run fine and the messages are recieved by all the generated actors. All 5 of them.

```
package package1.service;

import package1.akka.AkkaFactory;
import package1.akka.SystemType;
import package1.config.SpringExtension;
import package1.utils.StringUtils;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import akka.actor.ActorRef;

@Component
public class TestManager {

    @Autowired
    SpringExtension ext;

    public void test() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {

            //
            String actorName = "c" + new StringUtils().generateRandomKey(5);
            //generating a random string for the akka actor name.


            ActorRef testACTOR = AkkaFactory.getActorSystem(SystemType.LOCAL)
                    .actorOf(ext.props("testAKKAActor"), actorName);

            testACTOR.tell("MESSAGE", null);
        }

    }
}
```

We've looked into memory issues as well but that doesn't seem to be the problem.

If we remove the consumer codes the actors run fine and the messages are recieved by all the generated actors. All 5 of them.
We've hit a dead-end and are looking for some help.

Console logs:

```
2016-02-18 16:22:24.064  INFO 15835 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2016-02-18 16:22:24.065  INFO 15835 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2016-02-18 16:22:24.096  INFO 15835 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 31 ms
hi! message recieved
hi! message recieved
2016-02-18 16:22:24.195  INFO 15835 --- [t-dispatcher-10] package1.akka.TestAKKAActor                  : Consumer Activating for >> xkKmU4
2016-02-18 16:22:24.195  INFO 15835 --- [lt-dispatcher-5] package1.akka.TestAKKAActor                  : Consumer Activating for >> xW6yCq
hi! message recieved
2016-02-18 16:22:24.195  INFO 15835 --- [lt-dispatcher-2] package1.akka.TestAKKAActor                  : Consumer Activating for >> xnCPLM
2016-02-18 16:22:24.203  INFO 15835 --- [t-dispatcher-10] org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper           : Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=400 watcher=org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient@71eee08
2016-02-18 16:22:24.208  INFO 15835 --- [min.local:2181)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn          : Opening socket connection to server fadmin.local/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2016-02-18 16:22:24.208  INFO 15835 --- [lt-dispatcher-2] org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper           : Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=400 watcher=org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient@6bdda2eb
2016-02-18 16:22:24.209  INFO 15835 --- [min.local:2181)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn          : Socket connection established to fadmin.local/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session
2016-02-18 16:22:24.209  INFO 15835 --- [min.local:2181)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn          : Opening socket connection to server fadmin.local/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2016-02-18 16:22:24.209  INFO 15835 --- [lt-dispatcher-5] org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper           : Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=400 watcher=org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient@14e20f5f
2016-02-18 16:22:24.210  INFO 15835 --- [min.local:2181)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn          : Socket connection established to fadmin.local/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session
2016-02-18 16:22:24.211  INFO 15835 --- [min.local:2181)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn          : Opening socket connection to server fadmin.local/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2016-02-18 16:22:24.211  INFO 15835 --- [min.local:2181)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn          : Socket connection established to fadmin.local/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session
2016-02-18 16:22:24.226  INFO 15835 --- [min.local:2181)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn          : Session establishment complete on server fadmin.local/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x152f3af925700ab, negotiated timeout = 6000
2016-02-18 16:22:24.227  INFO 15835 --- [t-dispatcher-10] package1.kafka.SimpleConsumer                : Consumer started with group id: cj9UWsoFu
2016-02-18 16:22:24.259  INFO 15835 --- [min.local:2181)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn          : Session establishment complete on server fadmin.local/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x152f3af925700ac, negotiated timeout = 6000
2016-02-18 16:22:24.260  INFO 15835 --- [min.local:2181)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn          : Session establishment complete on server fadmin.local/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x152f3af925700ad, negotiated timeout = 6000
2016-02-18 16:22:24.268  INFO 15835 --- [lt-dispatcher-2] package1.kafka.SimpleConsumer                : Consumer started with group id: cUTZi2kSe
2016-02-18 16:22:24.269  INFO 15835 --- [lt-dispatcher-5] package1.kafka.SimpleConsumer                : Consumer started with group id: cJ6sE9NfW
```

As seen in the above logs, the "hi! message received" log is only printed 3 times. However, when removing the consumer codes. Messages are received all five times.

Comment: My guess is that your `while` loop processing the iterator over the stream never completes as the stream itself is non-terminal.  If this is the case then those actors will never finish their receive and thus not release their threads back to the dispatcher.  So I'm guessing the dispatcher is being starved and thus can not dispatch messages after 3 to the other actor instances.

Comment: Thanks for your input. After reading your comment I added this dispatcher and assigned it to the actor.
`blocking-io-dispatcher {`
  
`type = Dispatcher`
  `executor = "thread-pool-executor"`
  `thread-pool-executor {`
    `fixed-pool-size = 32`
  `}`
  `throughput = 1`
`}`

I was able to get around 12 consumers running using this but after that I've hit a dead end. Any advice as to what I can do to get through this?

thanks